# How do you find the angle between two vectors if the only thing you know is their magnitudes, sum and difference?

Tags: vectors

This was a physics homework problem. I already submitted it, but I still want to know how to solve this problem.

Vector B→ is 5.0 cm long and vector A→ is 4.0 cm long.
Find the angle, in degrees, between these two vectors when |A→ + B→| = 3.0 cm and |A→ − B→| = 3.0 cm.

I tried using vector equations and pythagorean theorem to derive what the components were, but I got stuck and there was so many different variables I gave up. How do you do this?

Comment: Well, $(\vec A+\vec B)\cdot (\vec A+\vec B)=|\vec A|^2+2\vec A \cdot \vec B +|\vec B|^2$ and $(\vec A-\vec B)\cdot (\vec A-\vec B)=|\vec A|^2-2\vec A \cdot \vec B +|\vec B|^2$ so...

Comment: The magnitudes of the two vectors and the magnitude of the difference are 3 sides of a triangle.  So use the law of cosines to find the angle.

Comment: [Polarization identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)

Comment: Alright. I figured it out. Thanks.